# Android NestedScrollView align content on top

Tags: android, android-activity, scrollview, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout

I noticed the content in a NestedSCrollView inside a CoordinatorLayout always aligns on the bottom if it does not fill the entire screen. How can I fix that?

My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <ListView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:divider="@color/black_200"
                android:dividerHeight="-7dp"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent_yellow"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/accent_dark_yellow"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see, the CardView inside the NestedScrollView is 200dp high, and aligns on the bottom.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following property in `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make suere u set the correct anchor.

Change *  android:layout_gravity="top"*  to *app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"*

Comment: unfortunately, that did not fix it. How should I use it? Just use app:layout_anchorGravity="top" instead of  android:layout_gravity="top"? Also, should I put that in the LinearLayout?

Comment: did u put the attributes on the linearlayout or the nestedlayout?

Comment: Nope, didn't fix it :(